# Is this matrix identity correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-matrix-inequality

Is the following matrix identity correct

$$L^TS+S^TL \preceq \alpha^{2} L^TL+\alpha^{-2}S^TS$$

I don't exactly know the interval where $\alpha$ lies! Would be great if someone pinpoint it.

Comment: what is the range of $\alpha$ ?

Comment: I am not sure, I think $[0,\,1]$

Comment: Have you attempted to expand the semi-positive definite expression : $(\alpha L-\frac{1}{\alpha} S)^T(\alpha L-\frac{1}{\alpha} S)$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yea, thanks! I can accept is as an answer if you write!

Comment: Moreover, if $FF^t\leq I,$ then $LFS+S^tF^tL^t\preceq \alpha^2S^tS+\alpha^{-2}LL^t \forall \alpha\neq 0.$

Comment: @Park Interesting! Have you some reference for such (Loewner) inequalities ?

Comment: @JeanMarie $0\preceq \begin{pmatrix}\alpha S^t& \alpha^{-1}L\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I&-F^t\\-F&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha S\\\alpha^{-1}L^t\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Park references as in books or articles!